# Получить значения из json

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть обработчик.

```
$('.test').click(function() {

  var test = [];
  $(".inputs input").each(function(id) {
    var screens = ("\"" + $(this).attr('id') + "\" : " + $(this).val() + ",");
    test.push($(this).val());
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/test",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'jsonData=' + $.toJSON(test),

    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $(".total_count").text(data.total_count + " шт.");
      $(".sum").text(data.total_price);

      $('#set_modal').reveal({});
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

`success` Данные возвращаются в формате

```
{"total_count":21,"total_price":"3 655 106"}
```

Пытаюсь получить `data.total_count`, но оно не выводит. В чём проблема?

Comment: попрубуйте так `data[0].total_count`

Comment: неа, пишит undefined

Comment: а если прописать дата тайп dataType: "json",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте настройку `dataType: 'json'` и сможете получить данные таким образом `data.total_count`